# Getting error while including AngularJS multiple chosen directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chosen

I'm getting the following error while implementing the AngularJS chosen directive.

> Error:
>       TypeError: a.map is not a function
>           at nh.q.writeValue (angularjslatest.js:307)
>           at Object.e.$render (angularjslatest.js:328)
>           at angularjslatest.js:310
>           at angularjslatest.js:146
>           at m.$digest (angularjslatest.js:147)
>           at m.$apply (angularjslatest.js:150)
>           at l (angularjslatest.js:102)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.s.onload (angularjslatest.js:108)

**I'm explaining my code below:**

```
<select chosen 
        multiple 
        class="form-control oditek-form" 
        name="category" 
        id="category" 
        ng-model="category" 
        ng-options="s.value as s.name for s in listOfCategory">
</select>
```

**My controller code is given below.**

```
$scope.listOfCategory = [{
  name: 'Select Category',
  value: ''
}];

$scope.category = $scope.listOfCategory[0];

var fileURL = '';
var url1 = '../service/admin/vechile/service/service.php?action=getAllCategoryData';
var method = 'GET';
var data1 = '';

DataService.connectToServerSideScript(method, url1, data1).then(function(response) {
  if (response.length > 0) {
    angular.forEach(response, function(obj) {
      var cdata = {
        'name': obj.category_name,
        'value': obj.id
      };
      $scope.listOfCategory.push(cdata);
    })
  }
}, function(error) {

});
```

Here I'm getting all the data but those error is coming in browser console. Here I need to clear those error.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu this doesn't make sense. `angular.forEach` is able to iterate over objects and arrays.

Comment: Try `$scope.category=[$scope.listOfCategory[0]];`.

Comment: has your `response` already extracted the `data`? You might need `angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj){...`

Comment: Any feedback @subhra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your selected model as an array:

```
$scope.category = angular.isDefined($scope.listOfCategory[0]) ? 
                      [$scope.listOfCategory[0]] : [];
```

**Please note that this also fixes the following error message:**

> Error: TypeError: a.forEach is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a same kind of 'chosen multiple select' related problem, which was getting 3 times same error. Error log is like below. The solution may help others.

```
TypeError: a.map is not a function 
at mh.q.writeValue (angular.js:30513) 
at e.$render (angular.js:33327) 
at Object.c.$render (angular-chosen.min.js:7) 
at angular.js:29306 
at m.$digest (angular.js:18253) 
at b.$apply (angular.js:18531) 
at HTMLButtonElement. (angular.js:27346) 
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3) 
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

To bypass the issue, I have maintained 2 variables, one for a model variable and other for a saving variable. e.g.

In controller,

```
$scope.x = {
   draftVar: []
};

$scope.save = function(){
   $scope.x.savingVar = $scope.x.draftVar.join(',');
   save();
```

}

```
<select ng-model="x.draftVar" chosen multiple chosen-updater ng-options="xx.id as xx.name for xx in XXs"> 
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```